# Python combine 2 nested dictionary with multiple values for one key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 default dict.. I wanna combine these 2  .
Please help me .

```
{ Fun :{ 1:hi , 2: hello} , fun2 : {3: bye, 4: good bye}}
  {Fun :{ 1:abc , 2: xyZ} , fun2 : {3: qpr, 4: jkl}}
```

I want to combine these and get 'hi' and 'abc' under key 1 along with 'fun'

Comment: "'hi' and 'abc' " - joined together or as a list? Or someething else?

Comment: In python, dictionary keys are unique. It means you can only one 'Fun' in the same dictionary.

Comment: Such a thing is not present in the standard library. You can use a defaultdict( http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) though. 
Example code:-
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> md = defaultdict(list)
>>> md[1].append('a')
>>> md[1].append('b')
>>> md[2].append('c')
>>> md[1] // output will be ['a', 'b']
>>> md[2] // output will be ['c']

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769396/merge-duplicates-list-of-dictionaries-item-value

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary keys are unique. You can't have two values attached to one key.

However, you can construct a nested dictionary with sub-dictionaries mapping keys to lists of values. For this, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d1 = {'Fun': {1: 'hi', 2: 'hello'}, 'fun2': {3: 'bye', 4: 'good bye'}}
d2 = {'Fun': {1: 'abc', 2: 'xyZ'}, 'fun2': {3: 'qpr', 4: 'jkl'}}

from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for top_dict in (d1, d2):
    for k1, v1 in top_dict.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            dd[k1][k2].append(v2)

print(dd)

defaultdict({'Fun': defaultdict(list,  {1: ['hi', 'abc'], 2: ['hello', 'xyZ']}),
             'fun2': defaultdict(list, {3: ['bye', 'qpr'], 4: ['good bye', 'jkl']})})
```